# wxWidgets wxTextCtrl crash when deleting

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, wxwidgets

wxTextCtrl causes some memory allocation problem when tried to be deleted or it's value changed. Here's some code insight:

```
    wxTextCtrl* s = new wxTextCtrl(...);
    s->SetValue("abc");//crash
    delete s//crash
```

It's like all of its members are const's. Here is what VisualStudio says when it crashes:

```
    An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' 
    occurred in Unknown Module.

    Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. 
    This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

And even when i try the wxWidgets default destroy:

```
    parent->DestroyChildren(); //ofc the parent is wxPane passed in constructor of s
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Here's some actual code from the only functions calling wxTextCtrl:

```
  void AddButton::OnAction(wxSize* frame){

if ( !DoAction ){
    if ( ! thy )
    {

        thy = new wxPanel
            (mParent, -1, 
            wxPoint(0, 0),
            wxSize(PanelWidth, mParent->GetSize().GetHeight()), 
            wxBORDER_NONE | wxFRAME_FLOAT_ON_PARENT );
        thy->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(30,30,30));
        thy->Show();
        if ( ! AddPanelDialog ){
            //AddPanelDialog = (new _Text
                //(this, thy, "add link...", wxPoint(1, 30), wxSize(PanelWidth - 30, 20),
                //wxBORDER_NONE | wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER ));
            wxTextCtrl* s = new wxTextCtrl(thy, -1, "", wxPoint(1, 30), wxSize(PanelWidth - 30, 20),
                wxBORDER_NONE | wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER );
            s->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_TEXT_ENTER, wxCommandEventHandler(_Text::OnEnter));
            s->Show();
        }
        if ( !ConfirmPanel ){
            ConfirmPanel = new wxPanel
                (thy, -1, wxPoint(PanelWidth - 28, 30), wxSize(27, 20), 
                wxBORDER_NONE | wxFRAME_FLOAT_ON_PARENT );
            ConfirmPanel->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(38, 145, 232));
            ConfirmPanel->Show();
        }

    }
    else {
        thy->Show();
    }
    gui* rmd = (gui*)mParent;
    rmd->LeftPanelActivate();
    rmd->SetNewPositions(rmd->GetParent()->GetSize());
    Button::Update();
    helper::SendRedrawEvent(mParent);
    DoAction = true; // indicates action activated
}
else{
    thy->Hide();
    gui* rmd = (gui*)mParent;
    rmd->LeftPanelActivate(false);
    rmd->SetNewPositions(rmd->GetParent()->GetSize());
    Button::Update();
    helper::SendRedrawEvent(mParent);
    DoAction = false; // indicates action activated
}
    }
```

and function that calls SetValue()

```
   void AddButton::OnEnter(wxCommandEvent& event)//enter button handler
   {
       wxTextCtrl* _t = (wxTextCtrl*)this;
       _Clear();
       *_t<<"sup";
   }
```

Comment: There is obviously a bug elsewhere in your code, you must understand that calling `SetValue()` can't crash if there is nothing wrong somewhere else. But you don't tell us anything about the rest of your code, making it impossible to help you.

Comment: @VZ. There I added some more code. I'm implementing the app with IMPLEMENT_APP macro. Everything else is as usual as it can be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem with understanding of `Connect()`. If you're using it to connect to a method of a different object, you **must** pass a pointer to this object as the last argument (called `eventSink` in [the documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#a78719e8b82c9f9c6e4056b3449df1943)). Your method is almost certainly being called on a wrong object pointer.

And you should absolutely never, ever have to cast `this` like you do in `OnEnter()`.

Comment: Even when passing this to Connect and many other random tries it continued to crash. However, i switched from version 2.9.5 to 2.8 and this problem was gone when i used `Connect()` the right way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you really need to delete the wxTextCtrl? If this text control is placed into sizer then sizer is responsible for it and will destroy it when needed. You probably need to detach the text control from sizer and then delete it.
Also you should use [Destroy()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a6bf0c5be864544d9ce0560087667b7fc) method instead of `delete` operator. This is clearly explained in docs.

As for crash on `SetValue()` call: have you tried to use `wxT("abc")`? Also what version of wxWidgets, OS and compiler are you using? Haven't experienced such problems with wxWidgets at all. Maybe you could post some meaningful piece of code which can help to identify the problem?

Comment: @T_Rex I tried detaching it from the sizer still got the crash. Also tried detaching its parent from sizer and nothing still crash. Also, I don't really need to delete the wxTextCtrl but the same error happens when I try to `wxTextCtrl::SetValue("");` to delete entry because `wxTextCtrl::Clear()` doesnt work.

Comment: @T_Rex yes i have tried that. I'm using wxWidgets-2.9.5 Visual studio 2010 on windows 7. Also I'll put more code in edit, hopefully will help.